# How to loop over groups and columns at the same time in R?

Tags: r, function, apply, multiple-columns, group

I have a dataframe which looks like this example, just much larger:

```
Name <- c('Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary')
date <- c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03','2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03','2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03')
var1 <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 , 0.7)
var2 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4 , 0.2)
var3 <- c(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5 , 0.2)
df <- data.frame(Name, date, var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to loop over the grouped names and columns to apply a function. I can do it for one group at a time with `apply`, but not over all groups:

```
list= apply(df[1:3,3:5],1,function(x){
      return(
        list(
      summary(x)
))})
```

The output in this case (i.e., for the name "Peter") is a list with the elements "var1" , "var2", "var3". The desired output would be a list with the "Name" elements, which contains the elements "var1", "var2", "var3" (or the other way round, the "var" elements containing all "Name" elements).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking at the package [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), which has a lot of handy functions for this kind of data wrangling. You haven't explained what exactly you're trying to do, but in general:

- First you use the command `group_by()` to group your dataframe by the values in one column. It looks like you want to use the column `Name`.
- To keep the same number of rows and compute new values you use the command `mutate()`.
- To run summary functions that return one row per group, use the function `summarise()`.
- You can chain these commands together using the pipe operator `%>%`.

So in your case, using the data you provided, if for each group you wanted to get the minimum value of `var1`, the mean of `var2`, and the maximum of `var3`, you would run:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(var1 = as.numeric(var1),
         var2 = as.numeric(var2),
         var3 = as.numeric(var3)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(var1_min = min(var1),
            var2_mean = mean(var2),
            var3_max = max(var3))
```

First we convert `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` to numeric values, since you've entered them as strings. Then we group by `Name`. Then we create a summary data.frame with three columns named `var1_min`, `var2_mean`, and `var3_max`.

[This is a helpful resource for more.](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

*EDIT TO ADD*

If you want to 1. group variables based on a values in the column Name, 2. then run arbitrary functions on the other columns, you can also do this with `tidyr::nest().` Consider:

```
nested_results <- df %>%
  tidyr::nest(cols = -Name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cols = purrr::map(cols, summary))
```

Which gives the results:

```
nested_results

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Name  cols           
  <chr> <list>         
1 Peter <table [6 × 4]>
2 Ben   <table [6 × 4]>
3 Mary  <table [6 × 4]>
```

And each Name's summary table can be accessed as you'd expect:

```
nested_results$cols[[1]]

     date                var1             var2             var3       
 Length:3           Min.   :0.4000   Min.   :0.2000   Min.   :0.2000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:0.5000   1st Qu.:0.3000   1st Qu.:0.4000  
 Mode  :character   Median :0.6000   Median :0.4000   Median :0.6000  
                    Mean   :0.5667   Mean   :0.3667   Mean   :0.5667  
                    3rd Qu.:0.6500   3rd Qu.:0.4500   3rd Qu.:0.7500  
                    Max.   :0.7000   Max.   :0.5000   Max.   :0.9000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not help me as my question is about looping. However, I changed the columns to numeric values and added an exemplary function to make my question clearer. @ChristopherBelanger

Comment: A for loop could be one way of doing it, but you may not need to use a loop. I've edited the response to show how you can use `tidyr::nest()` to run arbitrary functions on grouped columns.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Christopher Belanger's answer, you might also consider `mutate(across())` or `summarize(across())`, which facilitates applying the same function/transformation to multiple columns.

An example:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarize(across(var1:var3, ~mean(as.numeric(.x), na.rm=T)))
```

Output:

```
  Name   var1  var2  var3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ben   0.467 0.367 0.4  
2 Mary  0.567 0.233 0.4  
3 Peter 0.567 0.367 0.567
```